# as.h2o wrong encoding special characters

Tags: r, h2o

I am using the h2o package, in which I have a data.frame with special characters, however when using the `as.h2o` function there is a character conversion issue. Anyone know a solution.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

df = data.frame(Nombre = c("Juan Díaz", "Pedro Sánchez", "Sandra López"), Edad = c(23, 34, 56))
df
         Nombre Edad
1     Juan Díaz   23
2 Pedro Sánchez   34
3  Sandra López   56
> as.h2o(df)
  |============================================================================================| 100%
              Nombre Edad
1     Juan DÃ¯Â¿Â½az   23
2 Pedro SÃ¯Â¿Â½nchez   34
3  Sandra LÃ¯Â¿Â½pez   56

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

I am using the next version of h2o

```
packageVersion("h2o")
[1] ‘3.30.0.6’
```

Comment: I tested this on 3.30.0.6 with R 3.6.2. What version of R are you using? Note that R 4.0 is not yet supported and coming soon: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7673

Comment: I'm using 4.0.2 version of R.

Comment: R 4.0 is not yet fully supported. It would be better to use R 3 to avoid unexpected bugs.